# Fragmented Dojo Build documentation

Tags: dojo

I was looking for a way to automatically exclude modules included in common layers from other layers to reduce the amount of repeated code in our build.   Doing a google search, I ran across "layerDependencies" from https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/profiles.html?highlight=layerdependencies. Prior to this, I'd been looking at the writeAMD documentation at [enter link description here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/build/transforms/writeAmd.html#build-transforms-writeamd).  Both of these pages seem to be for Dojo 1.8 but contain what seem to be mutually exclusive definitions of what can go in a layer definition ('copyright' vs 'copyrightFile', for example).

My gut tells me one of these docs is outdated and should be deprecated, and sadly, my gut also tells me it's probably the former link.  However, layerDependencies worked in my build when mixed in with the syntax from writeAMD.

Are both of these documents valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, `layerDependencies` is part of the old (pre 1.7) build system.  The current build code moves `layerDependencies` to `exclude`.

**util\build\v1xProfiles.js**

```
layer.exclude = transformLayerDependencies(layer.layerDependencies, layer.name);
```

This is the tutorial that I use when creating a build.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/

---

EDIT - Clarify my usage of the exclude property

The exclude is an array of modules to exclude, not a layer.  So in the profile, I define a variable that contains a set of modules,

```
var profile = (function(){

    var coreRequires = [        
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/fx",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/currency",
        "dojo/fx",
        "dojo/number",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/query"
    ];

    ...
```

I then use this variable when defining the includes and excludes for layers.

```
    layers: {
        "myApp/core": {
            include:    coreRequires
        },

        "myApp/appLayer1": {
            include:    [
                "myApp/CustomWidget1",
                "myApp/CustomWidget2",
                ...
            ],
            exclude: coreRequires
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can include layer (a) in an exclude for layer (b) and any modules built into layer a will be skipped when building layer b?